# Rails ActiveRecord return records where id exists in related table

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord, active-record-query

I have a Client model and a Product model where a Client has many Products and a Product belongs to a CLient.

I need to find a query that only returns Clients if they have a record in the Product table

clients table

```
id |      name
--------------
 1 | Company A
 2 | Company B
 3 | Company C
```

products table

```
id |      name |  client_id
---------------------------
 1 | Product A |         1
 2 | Product B |         1
 3 | Product C |         3
 4 | Product D |         3
 5 | Product E |         1
```

I only need Clients 1 3

For example something like

```
@clients = Client.where("client exists in products")  #something to this effect
```

Comment: does `@clients = Client.joins(:products)` works ? I think it'll do an INNER JOIN, which is (i think) what you want

Comment: That's a good question, I will test in console

Comment: @pjam It seems to return all of the products joined to the clients therefore I end up with duplicated client names.  Is there a way to limit the results to just the clients?

Comment: @pjam For example I only want the 4 records, not 214 which is the number of products I have in the products table.  The 214 are a combination of those 4 clients but I only want to return the 4 clients, not the 214 products those clients are joined to. I hope that doesn't confuse anyone.

Comment: I get what you want, but the query `Client.joins(:products)` is returning a collection of clients right ? the problem is that you have duplicate entry that's it ?

Comment: I'm going to edit my answer to illustrate exactly what it returns

Comment: I have an idea, might not be the best, but you can try it : `Product.joins(:client).map(&:client).uniq`

Comment: You were closer the first time.  simply needed to add uniq to your original suggestion. @client= Client.joins(:products).uniq  Thanks for helping me brainstorm all this

Comment: Glad I somehow helped you :)

Answer (score 23, accepted):

Simplest but not the fastest:

```
Client.where(:id => Product.select(:client_id).map(&:client_id))
```

SQL subquery (more faster):

```
Client.where("EXISTS(SELECT 1 from products where clients.id = products.client_id)")
```

Comment: That's a much better answer,  doesn't' return unnecessary columns that a join statement would include.

Comment: I really like this answer. The second query allows me to compare against a non-active record table that's in the same DB.

Answer (score 7):

Here's another solution. It's a subquery like Valery's second solution, but without writing out the sql:

```
Client.where(Product.where(client_id: Client.arel_table[:id]).exists)
```

Comment: this does not work for me (using postgresql adapter); keeps interpreting the arel_table param as a prepared value, and then erroring because it isn't one.

Comment: I just learned, that `.exists` is not part of the public API. This used to work until 4.1, but no more on 4.2.

Answer (score 6):

Here is the solution which uses [Where Exists](https://github.com/EugZol/where_exists) gem (disclosure: I'm its author):

```
Client.where_exists(:products)
```

Comment: Nice gem! Looks elegant!

Answer (score 1):

Another gem that exists to do that: [activerecord_where_assoc](https://github.com/MaxLap/activerecord_where_assoc) (I'm the author)

With it:

```
Client.where_assoc_exists(:products)
```

If you had to also specify some of the products, when you could do it like this:

```
Client.where_assoc_exists(:products, id: my_products.map(&:id))
```

Doing it without a gem makes it easy to do mistakes.

Read more in the [documentation](https://maxlap.github.io/activerecord_where_assoc/ActiveRecordWhereAssoc/RelationReturningMethods.html). Here is an [introduction](https://github.com/MaxLap/activerecord_where_assoc/blob/master/INTRODUCTION.md) and [examples](https://github.com/MaxLap/activerecord_where_assoc/blob/master/EXAMPLES.md).

Answer (score 0):

Also not the fastest but is concise:

```
Client.where(:id => Product.pluck(:client_id))
```